# combine several dependent variables

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, covariance, correlation

I have 3 boolean variables X,Y,Z (indicating if the same event has happened).

Let's assume the error of each of them is 0.3. This means, for example, that if X is true then the probability of an event is 70%. When X is false, the probability of an event is 30%. Same goes for Y,Z.

I have to find the probability(P) that the event has happened, given X,Y,Z have all indicated true.

If X,Y,Z were all independent (Pearson = 0) - then P = 1 - 0.3*0.3*0.3 = 0.973.

If X,Y,Z were all fully dependent (Pearson = 1) - then P = 1 - 0.3 = 0.7.

My question is: what is P, given the "Pearson correlation" between each pair((X,Y)(X,Z)(Y,Z)) is 0.5?

Comment: Just for clarification: by "error", you mean the probability of being 1 when there is no event ($P(X|\bar{A})$), the probability of being 0 when there is an event ($P(\bar{X}|A)$), the probability of there being an event when they are 0 ($P(A|\bar {X})$) or the probability of there being no event when they are 1 ($P(\bar{A}|X)$)?
It might be obvious for a native English speaker, but no to me, sorry.

Comment: 2 first options :)
I edited the question accordingly

Comment: Ok, thank you. Also, could you precise in what context this problem arises? I have some trouble trying to picture what type of variables you are considering.

Comment: In order to "keep it simple" I'll use a ball example:
There are 3 sensors to check if a ball is black or white.
Each detector with error rate of 30%.
I want to find the probability that a ball is white, given all three sensors say it is.

Comment: If you state it like this, I'd just naturally assume that the sensors are independent, and thus the result is the first you give. Even if you tried with three times the same sensor, you could reasonably assume (most of the time) that the past measurements do not influence the new one, and that the three measurements are therefore independent.

Comment: My question is given the sensors are dependent, with Pearson correlation of 0.5.
It might be if the way the detect the ball is somewhat alike. For example one detector detects whether it is a very bright color, and the other one detects whether it was created in a year in which mostly white balls were created, etc..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93910/discussion-between-milloupe-and-user1028741).